# System.FormatException error and having issues trying to fix it

Tags: c#, console-application

Hello I am currently having issues with my project. im currently having issues with my console program where i am taking a users inputs (of which is decimals) and then using them in a if els statements, then finally doing the final math to work out ticket cost.

i have been researching into ways that i could fix this but for the past few hours i haven't been able to find a fix.

i have tried using strings, inter, var and boolen to store the price but when it comes to the final math to work out the cost, only inters do not give me a error.

i think a fix would be to change the way a user chooses the ticket they want but i cannot work out a way of allowing them to pick from the menu of tickets, while having the price values assigned to their input say:

```
Int family = 39.90
```

and then using this in some way to asinge the users input a value based on what i state.

Please could anyone suggest a way that i could maybe do this different or a solution to my current division / FormatException error ?

also any other tips on format ect would be much appreciated, all criticism is welcome im trying to learn.

Current console code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

 namespace The_Admission_Price_Calculator
 {
 class Program
 {


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Action<string> cw = Console.WriteLine;

        cw("Hello welcome to the WildLife park");
        cw("We currently have 4 ticket options:");
        cw("1: Famliy ticket(2 adults + 3 children) £39.90"); 
        cw("2: Adult ticket £14.90");
        cw("3: Child (under 16) £9.90");
        cw("4: Senior (over 65) £7.00");

        cw("Please input the price of the ticket you would like?");
        cw("(EG if you want to child ticket please input 9.90, please also include the decimal place.");
        cw("Input your the tickets price you would like to order now please.");

        string Answer1;
        int TicketCost1;
        int TicketAmount1;
        int TicketType1;



        TicketType1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        if  (TicketType1 == 39.90)
                {
                //int Famliy = 3990;   
                }

             else if (TicketType1 == 9.90)
                    {
                    //int Child = 990;
                    }

                        else if (TicketType1 == 14.90)
                        {
                        //int Adult = 1490;
                        }

                            else if (TicketType1 == 7.00)
                            {
                            //int Senior = 700;
                            }
                                else
                                {
                                Console.WriteLine("you need to Input from the options, using the price of the ticket, with the decimal included.");
                                TicketType1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        }



        cw("your choosen ticket is " + TicketType1 + ", how many tickets of this type would you like?");
        TicketAmount1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        //Rember to Add /100 to the final sum, so that the output is in decimals.  


        TicketCost1 = TicketAmount1 * TicketType1;




        cw("With the choosen amount of tickets of " +TicketAmount1+ " this will cost £" +TicketCost1+" ");

        cw("Is this correct? (YES OR NO");
        Answer1 = Console.ReadLine();
        if (Answer1 == "YES")
        {
            cw("Tickets are printing now.");
        }

        if (Answer1 == "NO")
        {
            cw("Please reselect what tickets you would like");
            //code here
        }

        else
        {
            cw("You have not entred a vaild asnswer please Input YES Or not in captials");
            Answer1 = Console.ReadLine();
            //core here
        }



        Console.ReadKey();

    }

}
```

}

Comment: What's  `cw` function?

Comment: How can any int (`TicketType1`) equal 39.90 or 9.90 or any other *float* value?

Comment: Use int.TryParse to parse integers and decimal.TryParse to parse you money values. Decimal work way better than doubles for fixed point items like you are using (particularly for equality comparisons)

Comment: @D-Shih if you use Action<string> cw = Console.WriteLine; it basicly is just a shortcut for rather console.writeline

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing i'd change is to have the user input the number of the option instead of the price when making a selection from the menu which should make things a little easier for you (then the selection is an int)

Like everyone is advising, switch from using int to decimal.

Which affects your conversion from string input too:

```
//TicketType1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());   
TicketType1 = Convert.ToDecimal(Console.ReadLine());
```

it also affects the way you do comparisons:

```
// if (TicketType1 == 39.90)
   if (Decimal.Compare(TicketType1,39.90) == 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

you cannot put decimals into an int. ints hold whole numbers. Traditionally you use double to store fractional things, but this is bad habit for currency. For currency use the decimal type http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Decimal.aspx

Comment: please update the question to show your updated code